# Very Simple MySQL INNER JOIN failing

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my simple Inner Join:

```
SELECT paintings.*, locations.*
 FROM paintings
 INNER JOIN locations
 ON locations.work_type = 'paintings' AND locations.work_id = 'paintings.id'     
 WHERE locations.location LIKE '%19th%'
```

It returns zero results. I expect it to find every painting row that has a match in locations table, based on having a common work_type and id. I know there are matches because

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location LIKE '%19th%' AND work_type = 'paintings'
```

I get 1000+ results.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change this part:

```
locations.work_id = 'paintings.id'
```

to this:

```
locations.work_id = paintings.id
```

Your current query requires that the `locations.work_id` field contain the actual literal value "paintings.id"; what you want is to require that the `locations.work_id` field contain the *same* value as the `paintings.id` field.

Comment: Ah! duh. Thank you!. I wish I could thank you all, but the race belongs to the swiftest, as they say. But thank you all so much. What a dumb error.

Comment: @user399696: You're welcome! (Though I think the saying is actually that the race is *not* given to the swift. At least, that's what Ecclesiastes 9:11 says, and I'm not familiar with any other related sayings.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `ON` clause contains an error, being:

```
AND locations.work_id = 'paintings.id'
```

You are using single quotes, which makes it a string literal. Replace those with backticks and you should be fine:

```
AND locations.work_id = `paintings`.`id`
```

Comment: Ah! duh. Thank you!. I wish I could give you all answer points, but the race belongs to the swiftest, as they say. But thanks so much. What a dumb error.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT p.*, 
       loc.*
  FROM PAINTINGS p
  JOIN LOCATIONS loc ON loc.work_id = p.id
                    AND loc.work_type = 'paintings'
                    AND loc.location LIKE '%19th%'
```

The problem was the single quotes around `paintings.id` - this makes SQL interpret it as a string, rather than a column for the JOIN criteria.  MySQL supports `JOIN` syntax without ensuring there is a relation to another table - in these cases, it'll produce a cartesian product.

Additional:

- `p` and `loc` are table aliases, so you don't have to type the entire name every time.
- backticks (`) are used by MySQL to escape text, in cases where you use [MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).  Otherwise, they are not necessary and I recommend not using reserved words.
- the placement of JOIN criteria doesn't matter for INNER JOINs, but does for OUTER - be careful.

Comment: Ah, very cool. I almost never use aliases, generally, they confuse me. That's a good note about backticks. I have tended to avoid the reserved words, but it is tough when something like "order" is the perfect column name. Anyway, thank you for the extended answer, I appreciate the chance to learn.